# Custom SQL Query in Tableau

Tags: sql, tableau-api

Does using 'custom SQL' instead of joins in Tableau increase the performance of extract refresh on the server? Can someone explain it briefly?

Comment: Hi...check out this link https://interworks.com/blog/zgorman/2015/08/25/tableau-performance-checklist-custom-sql-limit-live-connections/

Answer (score 1):

The answer to almost every performance question is first, "it depends" and second, test and understand the measurement results. Real results carry more weight than advice from anyone on the Internet (from me or anyone else)

Still, custom SQL is usually not helpful for increasing performance in Tableau, and often hurts. It is usually much better to define your relationships in Tableau and let Tableau then generate optimized SQL for each view -- just as you let a compiler generate optimized machine code.

When you use custom SQL, you prevent Tableau from optimizing the SQL it generates. It has to run the SQL you provide in a subquery.

The best use case for custom SQL in Tableau is to access database specific features, or possibly windowing queries. Most other SQL functionality is available by using the corresponding Tableau features.

If you do have a complex slow custom SQL query that you must use, it is usually a good idea to make an extract so you only pay the performance cost during extract refresh.

So in your case, I'd focus effort on streamlining or eliminating the custom SQL, monitoring the query plan for the generated SQL, and indexing your database to best support that query.

Comment: I will second everything Alex said. In my experience, the #1 reason to avoid custom SQL is because the customer will almost always change their mind on which grain and attributes they want to use. In nearly 100% of my custom SQL, I have had to go back and rewrite it because the customer either wanted to drill down further or they wanted more flexibility to create their own calculations. The power of Tableau is in self-service data exploration. Custom SQL usually locks you in to a fixed data set that limits data exploration.